# Beautiful Soup find_all() not working as expected

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm doing a project for an online course, and trying to extract the titles of the 100 movies on this site: https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2/

The code below outputs '[]'. If I change the code to 'all_movies = soup.find_all("title")' it works fine, and I've even removed the class_ tag from the code below which gets me nothing, but there are definitely h3 elements when I inspect the website, obviously.

Been trying this and that for ages, I'm at a loss. What am I missing?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2/"

response = requests.get(URL)
website_html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_html, "html.parser")

all_movies = soup.find_all(name="h3", class_="jsx-424597460")

print(all_movies)
```

Comment: Have you tried all_movies = soup.find_all("h3") ?

Comment: There's a difference between what you see in your browser and what is in your HTTP response. If you look at the source (`view-source:https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2/`) you'll see the source doesn't have h3 elements. They're created by JavaScript on the page.

Comment: @sytech I haven't done JavaScript yet, what's the difference between view-source and inspect? The instructor of the course has a video and she found the right information the same way I failed to.

Comment: Yes! They are often very different on most sites using JavaScript (most sites use JS!). Inspect will provide you the DOM including any processing performed by JavaScript. view-source will provide you only the original HTML document, with no processing at all. What you see in view-source is what you get from `requests.get(...)`. You can print out the response to see for yourself. `print(response.text)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res=requests.get("https://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/best-movies-2/")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
```

Try with class selector using `select` method and also if you analyze `img` tag is also containing your movie name which can be extracted finding `alt` from it

```
data=soup.select("img.jsx-952983560.loading")
lst= [i['alt'] for i in data if i['alt']!=""  ]
```

Output:

```
The Godfather
Stand By Me
Raging Bull
Amelie
Leonardo DiCaprio and Kate Winslet in Titanic
Good Will Hunting
Arrival
Lost In Translation
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I had run some tests

```py
review_text = []
review_text_ele = soup.find_all('h3')
    
for item in review_text_ele:
    review_text.append(item.text)

    print(item.text)
```

Nothing output

```py
review_text = []
review_text_ele = soup.find_all('h2')
    
for item in review_text_ele:
    review_text.append(item.text)

    print(item.text)
```

```sh
Empire's list of the best movies of all time – as voted by readers
Empire's 100 Greatest Movies Of All Time
```

with h2 tag, it run

```py
review_text = []
review_text_ele = soup.find_all(class_ = 'jsx-4245974604')
    
for item in review_text_ele:
    review_text.append(item.text)

    print(item.text)
```

```sh
GalleryEmpire's 100 Greatest Movies Of All Time
Gallery
Empire's 100 Greatest Movies Of All Time
1 of 100
1 of 100
1986
Rob Reiner's adaptation of Stephen King's novella The Body is a stirring, touching adventure film which knows the real world is exciting and scary enough just as it is. It's also a coming-of-age movie which celebrates the intensity of childhood friendship, while gently mourning the transience of such bonds. Which is why, unlike its central character, it'll never get old.
Read Empire's review of Stand By Me
Buy the film now



2 of 100
2 of 100
1980
Martin Scorsese and Robert De Niro have together made movies better than their boxing biopic, but it's hard to argue that any of those movies feature a more jaw-dropping performance than De Niro's here as self-destructive pugilist Jake La Motta. It also features some of cinema's best-shot fights; hard to believe that before Scorsese, no director thought to put the camera inside the ring...
Read Empire's review of Raging Bull
Buy the film now
```

With the class name which I believe you mistyped it, `class_ = 'jsx-424597460'`
It printed anything but the movie titles
I tried to block javascript on the page and it didn't show any titles either. There is no h3 content on the raw html source-code